# IP host management in truffle_config.js (Private Ethereum Network)

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle, transactions, private-blockchain, aws

I have 3 **Amazon Ec2 instances** (each with a **Geth** node running on them) and I'm running over them my Private Geth Ethereum (**PoA**) blokchain and I wanted to ask if it was necessary to specify the IPs of all 3 of my amazon AWS machines when I define the

```
networks:{
   geth:{
      host: ip-aws-machine,
      port: 8546,            
      network_id: "netID",       
      from: "address",  
   }
}
```

in the `truffle_config.js`.

For example, if the machine with the ip that I entered in truffle_config.js shuts down, my network will be unusable.

Since the `truffle_config.js` allows me to enter only one IP, I don't want that when I launch the transactions, they all end up on the node referring to that specific IP. Do you think I have to handle this thing to avoid problems or will the PoA consensus algorithm take care of it?